# How to decrease the learning rate every 10 epochs by a factor of 0.9?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to set the learning rate at 10^-3 with a decay every 10 epochs by a factor of 0.9. I am using the Adam optimizer in Tensorflow Keras. I have found this code in the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules/ExponentialDecay):

```py
initial_learning_rate = 0.1

lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate,
    decay_steps=100000,
    decay_rate=0.96,
    staircase=True
)
```

I do not know what is this `decay_steps=100000`. Actually I want to decrease my learning rate after 10 epochs. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve what you want with the use of a custom callback. The code for that is below. In the callback model is the name of your compiled model. freq is an integer that determines how often the learning rate is adjusted. factor is a float. The new learning rate= old learning rate X factor. Verbose is an integer. If verbose=0 no print out is produced. If verbose=1 a print out is produced each time the learning rate is adjusted.

```
class ADJUSTLR(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__ (self, model, freq, factor, verbose):
        self.model=model
        self.freq=freq
        self.factor =factor
        self.verbose=verbose
        self.adj_epoch=freq
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        if epoch + 1 == self.adj_epoch: # adjust the learning rate
            lr=float(tf.keras.backend.get_value(self.model.optimizer.lr)) # get the current learning rate
            new_lr=lr * self.factor
            self.adj_epoch +=self.freq
            if self.verbose == 1:
                print('\non epoch ',epoch + 1, ' lr was adjusted from ', lr, ' to ', new_lr)
            tf.keras.backend.set_value(self.model.optimizer.lr, new_lr) # set the learning rate in the optimizer
```

for your case you want freq=10 and factor=.9

```
freq=10
factor=.9
verbose=1
callbacks=[ADJUSTLR(your_model, freq, factor, verbose)]
```

be sure in model.fit include callbacks=callbacks

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. How about optimizer like `opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
#opt = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])`

Comment: don't understand your question. This should work for any optimizer

Comment: I utilized in the following way:   `callbacks = [ADJUSTLR(model, freq, factor, verbose)]
 
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])                                                                                                            
model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=total_epoch, callbacks=callbacks, validation_data=(val_x, val_y), verbose=1)`

Comment: Please confirm, is it okay

Comment: Somehow it works! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I had tested it so I expected it would work

Comment: I have seen `tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau` here on this https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ReduceLROnPlateau. Its look like it will work same? Can we replace this instead of your custom callback. Please confirm.